# OneToOneField is not working django

Tags: python, django

I have create OneToOneField relation in model and want to get data related data

Here is my model code

```
class Login (models.Model):
    login_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    role_id = models.IntegerField()
    user_id = models.IntegerField(unique = True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'login'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.login_id

class Catcher(models.Model):
    catcher_id = models.OneToOneField('Login', to_field = 'user_id', primary_key = True)
    catcher_fname = models.CharField(max_length = 128, blank = True)
    catcher_lname = models.CharField(max_length = 128, blank = True)
    api_key = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'catcher'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.catcher_id
```

I have Login table and login_id is PK, 2 table is Catcher and catcher_id is PK key.

In Login table user_id is FK and that is related to Catcher_id(PK) in catcher table.

When i run a query on catcher table without relation it's return me table data

```
catcher_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
```

Query 
    loginDetail = Catcher.objects.get(catcher_id =742 ) # Runing succssfully

But when i create a relation it return an error

```
catcher_id = models.OneToOneField('Login', to_field = 'user_id', primary_key = True)

loginDetail = Catcher.objects.get(catcher_id =742 ) # Get an error

OperationalError at /login/login/
(1054, "Unknown column 'catcher.catcher_id_id' in 'field list'")
```

why it return me field name like this catcher_id_id ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all. If you are using keys you should not use 'id' in the name. Django use 'id' so then your column name in the database will be '**user_id_id**'. I think you don't want this name in your database. It is redundant.

Second thing, you should pass object to the query. Because OneToOneField is related to Login model, you should pass Login object. So try something like this, you have to change your values:

```
loginDetail = Catcher.objects.get(catcher_id=Login.objects.get(user_id=742))  # you should change only on 'login' and only on 'user'
```

But you can use join over the models (database tables) also:

```
loginDetail = Catcher.objects.filter(catcher_id__user_id=742)
```

And also based on [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) you should not use spaces between name of parameter and equal sign. Write only this: `.get(user_id=742))` not `.get(user_id =742))`